# mysql insert performance

Tags: mysql

Our DB has very bad insert and update performance. Most of the big tables take 2-3 seconds per insert. If we rebuild the table, time reduces to 0.02-0.03 which means about 40 inserts per second. Even that is pretty low, and we cannot afford to rebuild tables every now and then. It is a time-consuming process and locks the table for the duration.
If we group inserts into transaction the performance increases. But in our application we have a requirement of commiting the insert immediately.
Can anybody suggest what can be done to improve the insert performance.

Here is the mysqlreport from server if it indicates anything: One thing noteworthy is that Com_rollback is very high on our server. What can that possibly mean?

MySQL 5.0.51a-3ubuntu5.  uptime 2 22:23:11      Thu Mar 11 09:13:33 2010

__ Key _________________________________________________________________

Buffer used    70.03M of   3.00G  %Used:   2.28
  Current     552.19M            %Usage:  17.97
Write hit      78.74%
Read hit       99.63%

__ Questions ___________________________________________________________

Total         803.30M    3.2k/s
  Com_        606.44M    2.4k/s  %Total:  75.49
  QC Hits     130.15M   513.7/s           16.20
  DMS          47.99M   189.4/s            5.97
  +Unknown     18.69M    73.7/s            2.33
  COM_QUIT     32.23k     0.1/s            0.00
Slow (10)       3.24k     0.0/s            0.00  %DMS:   0.01  Log:  ON 
DMS            47.99M   189.4/s            5.97
  SELECT       40.94M   161.6/s            5.10         85.30
  INSERT        3.92M    15.5/s            0.49          8.16
  UPDATE        2.85M    11.2/s            0.35          5.93
  DELETE      291.57k     1.2/s            0.04          0.61
  REPLACE           0       0/s            0.00          0.00
Com_          606.44M    2.4k/s           75.49
  set_option  467.34M    1.8k/s           58.18
  rollback    126.23M   498.2/s           15.71
  commit       11.44M    45.2/s            1.42

__ SELECT and Sort _____________________________________________________

Scan           85.20k     0.3/s %SELECT:   0.21
Range           1.91M     7.5/s            4.67
Full join         126     0.0/s            0.00
Range check         0       0/s            0.00
Full rng join       0       0/s            0.00
Sort scan         914     0.0/s
Sort range    191.09k     0.8/s
Sort mrg pass       0       0/s

__ Query Cache _________________________________________________________

Memory usage  190.04M of   1.00G  %Used:  18.56
Block Fragmnt  24.36%
Hits          130.15M   513.7/s
Inserts        12.10M    47.8/s
Insrt:Prune  12.10M:1    47.8/s
Hit:Insert    10.75:1

__ Table Locks _________________________________________________________

Waited         52.96k     0.2/s  %Total:   0.08
Immediate      63.16M   249.3/s

__ Tables ______________________________________________________________

Open               64 of   64    %Cache: 100.00
Opened          1.07M     4.2/s

__ Connections _________________________________________________________

Max used          396 of  500      %Max:  79.20
Total          49.06k     0.2/s

__ Created Temp ________________________________________________________

Disk table      5.27k     0.0/s
Table          47.47k     0.2/s    Size: 200.0M
File               27     0.0/s

__ Threads _____________________________________________________________

Running            18 of  245
Cached              0 of    4      %Hit:  39.82
Created        29.53k     0.1/s
Slow                0       0/s

__ Aborted _____________________________________________________________

Clients        33.67k     0.1/s
Connects           13     0.0/s

__ Bytes _______________________________________________________________
Sent          227.04G  896.0k/s
Received      106.15G  418.9k/s

__ InnoDB Buffer Pool __________________________________________________

Usage           4.00G of   4.00G  %Used: 100.00
Read hit       99.96%
Pages
  Free              0            %Total:   0.00
  Data        251.34k                     95.88 %Drty:   0.86
  Misc          10807                      4.12
  Latched           2                      0.00
Reads          13.04G   51.4k/s
  From file     5.02M    19.8/s            0.04
  Ahead Rnd    133920     0.5/s
  Ahead Sql    246973     1.0/s
Writes        968.37M    3.8k/s
Flushes        19.42M    76.6/s
Wait Free           0       0/s

__ InnoDB Lock _________________________________________________________

Waits            1540     0.0/s
Current             0
Time acquiring
  Total       1239283 ms
  Average         804 ms
  Max           51521 ms

__ InnoDB Data, Pages, Rows ____________________________________________

Data
  Reads         6.86M    27.1/s
  Writes       21.30M    84.1/s
  fsync        13.42M    53.0/s
  Pending
    Reads           1
    Writes          0
    fsync           1

Pages
  Created       2.34M     9.2/s
  Read         23.39M    92.3/s
  Written      19.42M    76.6/s

Rows
  Deleted     291.57k     1.2/s
  Inserted    138.07M   544.9/s
  Read          7.21G   28.5k/s
  Updated       2.78M    11.0/s

Answer (score 0):

Check DISC IO parameters. Possibly you simlpy overload your disc subsystem - which would mean getting more discs, a RAID controller etc.

I have seen on Windows / SQL Server a custome rcomlpain about bad insert perforamnce, and the measurement showed average disc response time was 1.2 SECONDS - so overloaded was the disc. This should be in the 2 digit milliseecond area - like 15ms or.

Answer (score 0):

`Com_rollback` means 'commit rollbacks' I assume. This would mean that you have lots of transaction commits fail.

Generally I suspect that you're doing something out of the ordinary with your keys, especially your primary key (you have one, right?). How are your keys defined? Are you changing the columns on which the keys frequently? If your INSERT and UPDATE commands are much faster after you rebuild the table then it sounds like your primary key, upon which MySQL orders and stores your table's rows, are changing.

Putting your table definition up here should help (`DESCRIBE your_table_name` or `SHOW CREATE TABLE your_table_name` will do the trick – I'm partial to the latter format).